# Read a csv file on request in sapper, svelte

Tags: webpack, svelte, sapper

I am new to svelte, sapper. I am trying to read a csv file located at `src/_data.csv` from a `.js` file in routes. and it gives error of `no such file or directory`.  Can someone help to find the a way to implement it.  I am trying in [existing template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template#using-degit) with webpack as build-tool. Here is the structure

[image]

In `_post.js` I am trying to read a file present at the root `src/_data.csv`.

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const path = require("path");

const csvFilePath=path.join(__dirname, '_data.csv');
//console.log("csvFilePath", csvFilePath);
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then(function(data){
    console.log("json data", data)
})
```

My aim is to read a .csv file and convert it to `JSON`, possibly on every request. I know that webpack handles `__dirname` to `/` as well and there is no `.csv` file in `__sapper__` i.e the build. But not sure how to make it work in sapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rollup doesn't handle `__dirname`, you probably want to put the CSV file in a known directory *outside* `src` (e.g. `data/data.csv`) and read it that way:

```js
import csv from 'csvtojson';

csv()
  .fromFile('data/data.csv')
  .then(function(data){
    console.log("json data", data)
  })
```

As long as the `data` directory is deployed with the rest of your app, and you start the app with the correct `process.cwd()`, this will work. (If you're just deploying the contents of `__sapper__` then you may need to copy it into the deployed directory, but the basic principle is the same.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also for `Rethinking reactivity` :)